# How to apply Zip Compression in GnuPG Class of PHP

Tags: php, gnupg, pgp

I would like to compress message using [GnuPG PHP extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gnupg.php)

```
 putenv("GNUPGHOME=/var/www/.gnupg");
 //$gpg = new gnupg();
 $res = gnupg_init();
 $rtv = gnupg_import($res, $pubkey);
 gnupg_addencryptkey($res, $rtv['fingerprint']);
 $pgp_str = gnupg_encrypt($res, $str);
```

I would like to pass **compress-algo** parameter but haven't found way to pass, can someone suggest?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

Reference to [GPG Configuration](https://gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Configuration.html), create file **gpg.conf** inside .gnupg folder.

Then put options in gpg.conf, check this for [example](https://github.com/drduh/config/blob/master/gpg.conf)

check result using `gpg --list-packets -vv --show-session-key yourfilename.gpg`